# error binding to radgrid

Tags: vb.net, telerik, radgrid

I get an error 
DataBinding: 'Transactions+Location' does not contain a property with the name 'lngWarehouseID'.

my aspx:

```
<telerik:RadGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableHeaderContextMenu="True" ID="radLocationGrid" Skin="OMSSkin" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AllowFilteringByColumn="True" PageSize="30" BorderWidth="0px" BorderStyle="None" ShowStatusBar="True" DataSourceID="ldsLocation" GridLines="None" Style="outline: none;" OnRowDrop="radLocationGrid_RowDrop">
<MasterTableView TableLayout="Fixed" CommandItemDisplay="Top" DataKeyNames="lngWarehouseID,bActiveInd" ClientDataKeyNames="lngWarehouseID,bActiveInd" DataSourceID="ldsLocation">
```

my class:

```
Public Class Location
    Public lngWarehouseID As Integer
    Public lngCustomsLineItemDiscount As Integer?
    Public strCompany As String
    Public strCity As String
    Public strAddress_1 As String
    Public bActiveInd As Boolean
    Public dtmDateCreated As DateTime
    Public dtmDateUpdated As DateTime
End Class
```

i'm new in VB. do I miss something?
please help me

Comment: Does lngWarehouesID have to be declared as a `Property` in your location class? I'm grasping a little.

Comment: @clweeks do I have to put 'Public Property lngWarehouseID As Integer'? please give me more clue because i'm totally blank on this

Comment: Please provide your full mark up/aspx code of radgrid.

Comment: Well, when you tried declaring it `Public Property` as you wrote out above, did the error change?